# MITMf arp spoofing inconsistent

Tags: man-in-the-middle, kali-linux, arp-spoofing, mitmf

using MITMf I'm getting inconsistent results, sometimes it just works, other times it just doesn't... I'm wondering is it like that for others or am I doing something wrong?

the command I'm using just for arp spoofing no injecting or anything is:

```
python mitmf.py --log-level debug -i wlan0 --spoof --arp --gateway 10.0.0.138 --targets 10.0.0.1
```

It will often get stuck after printing

```
Http server online
DNSChef v0.4 online
SMB server online
```

It just stays there and nothing happens. 
Then I'll run the same command again and it seems to work, what changed?

also sometimes on the victim browser, it takes a long time to load a page, or it won't load at all but when it freezes on attack computer, on victim computer the pages load fast again... When it's working I usually have to refresh the page on the victim computer a few times..

on attacker computer I get

```
[ServerConnectionFactory] Server connection failed. 
[ServerConnectionFactory] Retrying via SSL
[ServerConnectionFactory] Server connection failed.
```

but it starts working again..

Is this normal or something wrong?

Thanks....

Comment: In the documentation of MITMF, example suggests that --gateway option should target the real gateway but in the example above you have used it with 10.0.0.138 which does not look like the gateway to me. Are you sure that you have understood the usage clearly?

Comment: Goktay makes a good point. Also, have you tried running Wireshark alongside it to see what actually is happening?

Comment: @GoktayKaykusuz yeah 10.0.0.138 is the router... and 10.0.0.1 is my other computer...

Comment: Will try with wireshark and see

Comment: @ReedJones Well, that is an odd IP choice for a router. Nevertheless man-in-the-middle tools never worked flawlessly for me. I've used Ettercap in the past and it kept failing and dropping people off the network. Instead of a configuration issue, it might be a bug in the MITMF tool. If nothing else works, my best suggestion would be trying different man-in-the-middle tools. I've yet to try but [Bettercap](https://www.bettercap.org) seems to be doing well.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was strange about the router too... Ok thanks, I'll try and mess around with some other tools and see, but regardless if it is a bug, mitmf is really awesome :)

Answer (score -1):

```
apt-get install mitmf
```

now that works

```
mitmf --log-level debug -i wlan0 --spoof --arp --gateway 10.0.0.138 --targets 10.0.0.1
```